# department wise Sum of salary of employee with each employee details

Tags: sql, sql-server

I Have following table which contains details of Employee

```
EmpId    EmpName   Mgr   Salary  Dept

1        Deepak     2     20000  1
2        Annu      NULL   22000  1
3        Jai        2     19500  1
4       Jitendra    1     18000  2
5       Vaishali    1     18000  2
6       Philip      4     15000  3
```

I wants to show salary of each dept with each employee details,if it repeats no issues as shown below

```
EmpId    EmpName    Mgr   Salary    Dept   DeptSal

1        Deepak     2      20000    1        61500
2        Annu      NULL    22000    1        61500
3        Jai        2      19500    1        61500
4        Jitendra   1      18000    2        36000
5        Vaishali   1      18000    2        36000
6        Philip     4      15000    3        15000
```

Comment: Anything you've tried so far ?

Comment: What is your question here? You've only told us what you want (SO isn't a website for asking others to write your code for you). What have you tried so far? Have you had a look at `SUM` (and `OVER`)? If not, and you haevn't tried anything, those would be good places to start. Look them up, and if you don't understand the documentation, or your attempt fails, ask about that. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should look into the SUM() OVER(PARTITION) windowing functions in SQL Server.
See this [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/sum-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) link
This link should help you in solving your problem.
If you are still compelled to get a solution rather than understanding how you can solve these type of problems, then answer is mentioned in a single line as spoiler below

```
select *, DeptSal=sum(Salary) over (partition by Dept ) from t
```

Comment: thank you ...Got the ans

Comment: If this solved your problem then please mark it as the solution @RiteshNaik. Show some appreciation for someone doing your work for you. :)